# Automatically save email attachments when user is not log in (C# or other)

Tags: c#, outlook, com, interop, scheduler

I try to do the program which will save specific email attachments automatically every day on specific hour.
I tried to use Outlook MAPI in C#, but I got lot of problems with setting this in Task Scheduler on server and run when user is not log on (thats how it needs to be done). Program can't receive COM class on below line:

`outlookApplication = new Application();`

I was searching for help 3 days and tried everything, but it still not working. Program works fine when is manually runned or when I'm logged on the server.
IMAP4 and POP3 need to be disabled.
Is there any way to resolve my problem in any programming language?

I get the following error:

> "Can't recaive COM Class". I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook class.

Comment: There is an option to start a task where user is logged on or not. Under the General Tab. What kind of app did you try this with?

Comment: I know and when I use this option program throw the error "Can't recaive COM Class". I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook class. This is just an console app.

Comment: Does your program run without the scheduler?

Comment: Yes. And with scheduler also. Only option "when user is logged on or not" is not working.

Comment: It seems to me that the instance of outlook is not running when signed off. I can only guess. Please edit your question and update the error you get. I am not familiar :). Especially the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook, just like any other Office app, cannot run in a Windows service. Keep in mind that Task Scheduler is a service.

If you are accessing an Exchange mailbox, consider using a different API, such as EWS.